# Magento custom rewrite URL issue with pagination

Tags: php, pagination, magento-1.9

I have a custom rewrite rule in my magento module.

Config.xml

```
<my_custom_url>
  <from><![CDATA[#^/authors/author/([0-9])/([-\A-Za-z0-9.]+)/([0-9])/([-\A-Za-z0-9.]+)/?$#]]></from>
  <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/author/books/author_id/$1/category_id/$3]]></to>
  <complete>1</complete>
</my_custom_url>
```

Final Output

from : http://example.com/authors/author/12/john/3/fiction

to: http://example.com/mymodule/author/books/author_id/12/category_id/3/

It works fine but my problem is that in this page has list of books with pagination. If i click on the 2d page in the pagination link, then the URL change to its actual URL.

For example if i click on 2d page, then the URL is

http://example.com/mymodule/author/books/author_id/12/category_id/3/?p=2

I really need like this

http://example.com/authors/author/12/john/3/fiction/?p=2